# Mysql Nested/Multiple Query handling

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have three queries gives me result individually correct but my requirement is i need all result in single query only so how should i proceed?

```
select * from user_post_like
inner join user_post  on user_post_like.postID = user_post.postID  
inner join Users on Users.userID=user_post_like.userID 
where (user_post.poster='$uid' AND user_post_like.userID!='$uid') 
ORDER BY likeID DESC;

select * from user_post_comment   
inner join user_post  on user_post_comment.postID = user_post.postID  
inner join Users on Users.userID=user_post_comment.commenter 
where (user_post.poster='$uid' AND  user_post_comment.commenter!='$uid') 
ORDER BY commentID DESC;

select * from user_post_share   
inner join user_post  on user_post_share.postID = user_post.postID  
inner join Users on Users.userID=user_post_share.Share_user_id 
where (user_post.poster='$uid' AND   user_post_share.Share_user_id!='$uid') 
ORDER BY shareID DESC;
```

Comment: I see a common join with user_post...maybe that is the answer

Comment: @RobertRozas can you,please  provide query?

Comment: @Datta excellent comment. The essence of Stack Overflow.

Comment: With the information given, those three queries seem extremely unrelated

Comment: @Ic i have three tables like ,comment ,share which contain data about post which is in table post and all user details in table user so i have three single queries working fine but how to combine all result

Answer (score 0):

Since you're joining the tables anyway, you can put columns from all in your select - and keep your statement readable.  If you have duplicate column names (from different tables) you may need to aggregate them with functions and group by.

```
SELECT s.*, p.*, u.* 
FROM user_post_share s 
INNER JOIN user_post p ON s.postID = p.postID 
INNER JOIN Users u ON u.userID = p.poster 
WHERE (p.poster='$uid' AND s.Share_user_id != '$uid') 
ORDER BY shareID DESC
```

Comment: thanks for your efforts. But this  query gives me only result from share table not from comment and like table and not from there user details

Comment: Mistake in the first, fixed now.

Comment: new query gives data from share table but not from like and comment table

Comment: I didn't get them all, but then I don't know your foreign keys either.  You have to join them all together by common links, and use distinct aliases for each table in both the joins and the select clause.

Answer (score -3):

try sumthing like this

```
select * from user_post_like,user_post_comment,user_post_share  <inner joins> <where conditions>
```

Comment: can u comment while downvoting?